# How remove github repository dependency from a test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following test:

```
describe "POST 'create'" do
  let(:url){ Rails.root.join('spec','files','example.git').to_s }

  it "redirect" do
    post 'create', repository: {url: url }

    expect(response).to be_redirect
  end
end
```

My controller code:

```
def create
  @repository = Repository.new repository_params

  process_and_assign_respository_data

  respond_to do |format|
    if @repository.save
      format.html { redirect_to @repository }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end

private

def process_and_assign_respository_data
  path = get_path
  name = Time.now.to_i.to_s

  Git.clone @repository.url, name, path: path
end
```

The create action clones a repository.
The test passes locally, but it breaks in Travis and shows this:

```
Failure/Error: post 'create', repository: { url: Rails.root.join('spec','files','example.git').to_s }

Git::GitExecuteError:

git clone "--" " &1:fatal: repository 'example.git' does not exist
```

I fixed it by changing `url` to a github repository.
Is There some way to remove the dependency on github repository and not break in Travis?

Comment: Please paste controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether the repo is a valid Github url or not. You just need fake data to test, either fixture or factory, while I prefer FactoryGirl.

```
# Define it in factory file
factory :repo do
  url: 'http://example.com/abc.git'
end

# Then test
describe "POST 'create'" do
  let(:repo_attr) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for :repo }

  it "redirect" do
    post 'create', repository: repo_attr
    expect(response).to be_redirect
  end
end
```

Comment: Didn't work
the problem is not the url, but the repository path, when passing local path on Travis does not finds the repository, only passes when I use github, bitbucket or similar

Comment: I see, you did some work on real repo. So you need to mock the response of `process_and_assign_respository_data` to return fake result to get the test pass. This method is not concern of this test and can be mocked.

Comment: mocking `process_and_assign_respository_data` worked